# Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the data similar to this dictionary and I am working on Win32 bit Win7 machine.

Following code working fine on Win64 bit Win10 but not in Win32.

I am getting this "TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'" if I run this on Win32 Win7.

I searched the answer everywhere and not sure where to put the .astype('int32') codes. in my code.

What I wanted to achieve was there are rows, for this case, 4th row, under PA column, data is with comma, I would like to split them into next row as well as respective columns "var2" and "var3". Something like this in separate row d with var2=2 and var3=65. Then, in another row, e with var2=2 and var3=65, then in another row, f is with var2=2 and var3=65.

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks millions.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = DataFrame([{'PA': 'a', 'var2': 1, 'var3': 3},
               {'PA': 'b', 'var2': 3, 'var3': 54},
               {'PA': 'c', 'var2': 54,'var3': 3},
               {'PA': 'd,e,f', 'var2': 2, 'var3':65}])

lst_col = 'PA'
x = a.assign(**{lst_col:a[lst_col].str.split(',')})

TS1 = pd.DataFrame({
         col:np.repeat(x[col].values, x[lst_col].str.len())
       for col in x.columns.difference([lst_col])}).assign(**{lst_col:np.concatenate(x[lst_col].values)})[x.columns.tolist()]
```

error:

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-4f61e3646357> in <module>()
     11 TS1 = pd.DataFrame({
     12          col:np.repeat(x[col].values, x[lst_col].str.len())
---> 13        for col in x.columns.difference([lst_col])}).assign(**{lst_col:np.concatenate(x[lst_col].values)})[x.columns.tolist()]
     14 

<ipython-input-12-4f61e3646357> in <dictcomp>((col,))
     11 TS1 = pd.DataFrame({
     12          col:np.repeat(x[col].values, x[lst_col].str.len())
---> 13        for col in x.columns.difference([lst_col])}).assign(**{lst_col:np.concatenate(x[lst_col].values)})[x.columns.tolist()]
     14 

D:\Users\gexakz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.pyc in repeat(a, repeats, axis)
    421 
    422     """
--> 423     return _wrapfunc(a, 'repeat', repeats, axis=axis)
    424 
    425 

D:\Users\gexakz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.pyc in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     60     # a downstream library like 'pandas'.
     61     except (AttributeError, TypeError):
---> 62         return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     63 
     64 

D:\Users\gexakz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.pyc in _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     40     except AttributeError:
     41         wrap = None
---> 42     result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
     43     if wrap:
     44         if not isinstance(result, mu.ndarray):

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Comment: Please paste the entire exception, because it will tell you _where_ this happens. Also, if it happens in that three-line comprehension, debugging will be a lot easier if you break that out into an explicit loop with as little as possible on each line, so you'll know exactly what part of it is failing instead of just something somewhere in this monster expression.

Comment: Hello abarbet, I have added the error message. Will it be helpful for u?

Comment: It helps, but not nearly as much as if you read the rest of my comment and did what I suggested there.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by entire exception. I am sorry. If run the code in current state, we can recreate the error. What I wanted to achieve was there are rows, for this case, 4th row, under PA column, data is with comma, I would like to split them into next row as well as respective columns "var2" and "var3".

Comment: You have posted the entire exception; that's fine. But you need to read the rest of the same comment, not just reread the first sentence. Debugging this any further than "something is wrong somewhere in that big three-line comprehension" will be a whole lot easier if you temporarily break it out into separate steps, e.g., a `for` loop that builds a key on one line, builds a value on another line, then adds them together to a dict. And if the exception happens in building the value, but that's still a complex expression, break that complex expression into separate lines, one per step. Etc.